# Semantic UI React (SUIR) Form with only a Form.Dropdown won't submit on Enter

Tags: reactjs, forms, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to build a form with a dropdown and a submit button with SUIR. The form is submitted when I click the button but not when I press Enter.

```
<Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
  <Button type='submit'>
    Submit
  </Button>

  <Form.Dropdown
    fluid
    selection
    options={options}
    onChange={onChange}
    value={value}
  />
</Form>
```

What is the best way to get both to work ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event Listener  "keydown":
If your are developing Function component with hooks api you can do something like:

```
import { Button, Checkbox, Form } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const MyForm = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        //13 is the Enter key code
        onSubmit();
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);
  function onSubmit() {
    console.log("submit function");
  }
  return (
    <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <Form.Field>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input placeholder="First Name" />
      </Form.Field>
      <Form.Field>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input placeholder="Last Name" />
      </Form.Field>
      <Form.Field>
        <Checkbox label="I agree to the Terms and Conditions" />
      </Form.Field>
      <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
    </Form>
  );
};
export default MyForm;
```

Or if you are using class component :

```
import "./styles.css";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";
import { Button, Checkbox, Form } from "semantic-ui-react";
import React from "react";

export default class FormClass extends React.Component {
  onSubmit() {
    console.log("submit class");
  }
  handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      //13 is the Enter key code
      this.onSubmit();
    }
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyDown);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyDown);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <Form.Field>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input placeholder="First Name" />
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input placeholder="Last Name" />
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <Checkbox label="I agree to the Terms and Conditions" />
        </Form.Field>
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

An other solution is to use the `onKeyPress`props this solution add another feature that to be execute on key the component need to be focus (the two other solution add an eventListner on all the document):
for example in a Class component (works too in a function component):

```
export default class FormClassKeyPress extends React.Component {
  onSubmit() {
    console.log("submit class on key press");
  }
  handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      //13 is the Enter key code
      this.onSubmit();
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} onKeyPress={this.handleKeyDown}>
        <Form.Field>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input placeholder="First Name" />
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input placeholder="Last Name" />
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <Checkbox label="I agree to the Terms and Conditions" />
        </Form.Field>
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

here you can see a [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-dust-kv525) example of both component type and onKeyPress

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I like the onKeyPress solution. I am surprised that there isn't a way to handle this directly with SUIR props though.